# Extract variable from Std Object

Tags: php, riot-games-api

here is the output of a var_dump of my variable $result

```
stdClass Object(
    [20365924] => stdClass Object(
        [id] => 20365924
        [name] => Jack
        [profileIconId] => 916
        [summonerLevel] => 30
        [revisionDate] => 1463062452000
    )
)
```

how to save only the '916' inside a variable, i have tried many things without success...

thanx.

Comment: don't give such names `20365924` to object properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it like this :

**PHP**

```
$variable = $result->20365924->profileIconId;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with this if `20365924` is a name

`$var = $result['20365924'][profileIconId];`

or this if `20365924` is an index

`$var = $result[20365924][profileIconId];`

Hope it helps.

EDIT: Grammar